# How to get response to email which sent by an application?

Tags: php, email, httprequest, html-email, httpresponse

I have an idea to do a survey using emails. But have no idea to  do it. Can anyone help me with it. I even don't know it is feasible or not.

Here i have an web application which send emails to some users of that app(or any other people) asking about a simple question. It's something like a survey.

Ex: The email which i sent has two buttons. **Yes** or **No**. (an answer to a given question). That's all.   so I will  send this email to many people. And i want them to respond. (Yes or No).

Is there any way to capture the response of the people. I mean if a reader click **yes** button  i want my DB to update it's table according to that. 
How can I do  something like this.

How can i embed something like that button clicking facility to an email.  ?

How can i trigger my application about the user  events. ?

Is there anyway to achieve a functionality like this ?? 
please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do that is have the buttons forward to a link on your server and register that  on your server using php.

Have button Yes forward to "/surveyResult.php?result=yes" and No forward to "/surveyResult.php?result=no" using HTML.

```
<a href="www.myserver.com/surveyResult.php?result=yes">Yes</a>
<a href="www.myserver.com/surveyResult.php?result=no">No</a>
```

in your surveyResult.php do something like this:

```
<?php
$result = $_GET["name"];
[write the result to your mysql-database]
?>
```

Comment: Please select an answer as the correct answer so this question is marked as answered.

Comment: More like "accepted" than necessarily "correct". But yes, please do.

Answer (score 2):

You can use following steps to solve the problem.

- Create an action to accept user response (Yes/No Button clicking)
- On button click (create a link in email and make it as button using css if required)
- On clicking button record the result

Eg:

Your email look like this

```
Hi User,

   Bla bla ....

   Please click on any options

   <a href="example.com/emailresponse?opt=yes">Yes</a>
   <a href="example.com/emailresponse?opt=no">No</a>


Regards,
XXX
```

Create one Servlet to accept user response

```
public class EmailResponse extends HttpServlet {


protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
   String option = request.getParameter("opt");
   //Save user option into db

}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you use mvc application(asp.net)
 Your email template look like this

Dr ....

```
 <a href="www.myserver.com/EmailResponse?result=yes">Yes</a>

 <a href="www.myserver.com/EmailResponse?result=no">No</a>
```

...
Thank you

you can create a controller to get email response...

```
public class EmailResponseController : Controller
   {
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        String result = Request.QueryString["result"];
        return View();
    }

}
```